# Finding the median of the total number of die rolls

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice, median

**Question**

A fair die is to be rolled repeatedly until a six comes up. Find the median of the total number of rolls given that five comes up on the first roll.

**My working**

Clearly, this follows a geometric distribution with $p = \frac 1 6$ and the median is given by $$-\frac 1 {log_2(1 - p)}$$ which evaluates to $4$, rounded up.

However, how do we factor in the fact that five comes up on the first roll? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The distribution of the number of rolls is the same, no matter whether the first roll is a $1$, a $2$, a $3$, a $4$, or a $5$—as long as it isn't a $6$. As such, the only thing it means is that the number of rolls wasn't $1$.

Comment: @BrianTung But doesn't the median come from solving $\left(\frac 5 6\right)^n = \frac 1 2$? If so, then given the fact that five comes up on the first row, shouldn't we be solving $(1)\left(\frac 5 6\right)^{n - 1} = \frac 1 2$ now, such that the median is increased to $5$, where the $1$ comes from the fact that our first throw is certain?

Comment: The die is memoryless (it doesn't remember how many times it has failed to roll a $6$ so far), so it just means that whatever the probability $p_k$ was for rolling $k$ times was, will just be $p_{k+1}$ now. That is, $p_1 = 0$ (instead of $1/6$), $p_2 = 1/6$ (instead of $(5/6)(1/6)$), etc. Does that give you enough to draw the necessary conclusion?

Comment: @BrianTung I see! Thank you! If you could write this as answer so that I may accept it and close the post, that'll be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The die is memoryless, meaning that it doesn't "remember" how many times it has failed to roll a $6$ so far. That means that the distribution for the number of rolls, conditioned on not rolling a $6$ on the first roll, is simply the original distribution of number of rolls, shifted to the right by $1$.

Symbolically, if we denote by $p_k$ the probability of rolling $k$ times, irrespective of the first roll, then the probability $q_k$ of rolling $k$ times, *given that the first roll was not a $6$*, is given by $q_1 = 0$ and $ q_k = p_{k-1}, k \geq 2$.

As a result, the median—as well as the mean, for that matter—is just shifted over by $1$ as well. So if you computed the median to be $4$ before, then now the new information just makes it $5$. (I'm not sure how median is defined for this problem.) Similarly, the original mean was $6$, so the new mean is $7$.